# Best way to see correlation between a categorical variable and numerical variable in python,

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a pandas dataframe which stores user id, their salary range(out of 3 possible ranges), and profit they generated as below:

```
  user_id     salary_range     profit_amount  
 --------- ------------------ --------------- 
      123   0 - 35,000                   324  
      654   50,000 - 100,000            2083  
      129   50,000 - 100,000           20023  
      654   0 - 35,000                   699  
      398   35,000 - 49,999              298
```

I would like to see if there is any correlation between a users salary range, and the profit they generate.

Typically I would use a `seaborn.heatmap` along with `pd.corr` but this only works for 2 numerical variables, and while salary is typically a numerical amount, here the range is a categorical.

Personlly, my method of solving this would be to rank the ranges from 1 to 3, and then generate a correlation from there. However I believe that there are other possible ways to do this, and would like to see if anybody can suggest an alternative correlation method between the range and profit?

Answer (score 1):

I believe correct way to get the association between `salary_range` and
`profit_amount` would be one way ANOVA.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"user_id":[123,654,129,654,398],
    "salary_range":["0 - 35,000","50,000 - 100,000","50,000 - 100,000","0 - 35,000","35,000 - 49,999"],
    "profit_amount":[324,2083,20023,699,298]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

from scipy import stats
F, p = stats.f_oneway(df[df.salary_range=="0 - 35,000"].profit_amount,
                  df[df.salary_range=="35,000 - 49,999"].profit_amount,
                  df[df.salary_range=="50,000 - 100,000"].profit_amount)
print("Statistics Values: ",np.round(F,2), "\n","P _Value        :",np.round(p,2))
```

Output:

```
Statistics Values:  0.84                                    
P _Value        : 0.54
```

If F score is towards 0, then there is no correlation between categorical column and continuous column. *That concludes that there no correlation.*

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the link between a quantitative variable and a qualitative variable you need to calculate Eta

If it can help you for, in R you can use this function : `etaSquared()` on an anova

Comment: Is this function built-in or do I have to install/load a specific library?